# Laravel Shopping cart destroy method delete all items in the card

Tags: php, laravel, shopping-cart

I use olimortimer LaravelShoppingcart My code is properly setup  however after adding items to the card it goes to a table each item has  a delete button however when i click one button it clear all cart items . i use \Cart::destroy($id); however when i debug it return null .
here's the code

Controller:

```
    public function destroy(Request $request, $id)
    {

        \Cart::destroy($id);
        $request->session()->flash('status', 'item deleted!');
        return redirect()->back();
    }
```

Comment: You're using the wrong method to remove an item. You need to use `Cart::remove($id)`. See https://github.com/olimortimer/LaravelShoppingcart#cartremove

Comment: yeah it works by using method remove($rowId) not $id. thanks